# Tensorflow hub: restore re-trained universal sentence encoder module

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I have been trying to retrain the universal sentence encoder module ([use](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3)) but I cannot seem to generate new embeddings from any updated/retrained module weights.

I have followed the [classifier example for `elmo`](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/text_classification_with_tf_hub) and replaced that with the use module. The classifier works I cannot seem to figure out how to get access to the new module `embeddings`. I can restore the saved model but not sure how i actually call the embedding function?
For example, previously I set the path via

```
m=hub.module(path) then generate the embeddings via

m(sentences)
```

But how do I make this call with a restored classifier model? Note that I do set the parameter to `trainable=True` as in the example tutorial.

Do I simply make the same call and it automatically picks up the new weights that have been trained via the classifier retraining?
I have checked for similar questions but most of them are related to manipulating the meta graph. I just want to simply use the new weights to generate some new embeddings to see if they are different having being fine tuned on other data.
Maybe this isnt possible?

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I actually ran into this problem when I was running distributed tensorflow and the loss was not changing.

The trick is that when you first download it you need to set trainable = True otherwise the weights will be locked.

So in your case, redownload the module with trainable = True to unlock the weights.